# Как грамотно сменить дистрибутив Linux, без потери ветки /home?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian

Здравствуйте.

Давным давно, установил на свой ноутбук Ubuntu 14.04. С тех пор, репозитории устарели и, простой возможности обновления не стало. Кроме этого, у меня стоит 32 битная ОС, что затрудняет обновление некоторых программ (например, Google Chrome). Решил обновиться до последней версии, но на этот раз, Debian.

Директорию /home я вынес в отдельный раздел. В итоге, у меня три раздела, а именно:
/ - sda1
/home - sda2
swap - sda3.

Я хочу сохранить раздел /home, в надежде его примонтировать после установки debian. Вопрос заключается в учетных записях пользователей. Подумываю, оставить прежние учётки.

Прошу совета по грамотному переходу на свежую версию ОС. Спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я уже делал так. Всё прошло без проблем.

1. Установил debian
2. Примонтировал старый /home
3. Прописал /home в /etc/fstab, чтобы он монтировался автоматом.
4. Всё заработало само.

Но проблемы на самом деле возникнуть могут. В домашней директории приложения хранят свои настройки в скрытых папках и файлах (начинаются с точки). Так вот я на всякий случай оставил только те скрытые файлы и папки, в которых у меня есть какие-то мои настройки или другие данные, а остальные взял те, что достались мне со свежей системой.

Т.о. если эти скрытые файлы и папки бекапить, то даже если какие-то приложения будут вести себя некорректно от того, что встретили свои файлы от старых версий, будет шанс попробовать что-то исправить с ними.

Для того, чтобы брать файлы из того /home, который идёт со свежей системой, можно предварительно просто скопировать его куда-то во вне /home.

Answer (score 4):

Для сохранения /home достаточно просто не забыть примонтировать его; установщик Debian предложит настроить точки монтирования.

> Вопрос заключается в учетных записях пользователей. Подумываю, оставить прежние учётки.

Для сохранения учёток достаточно скопировать строчки с интересующими вас учётками из файлов `/etc/passwd` (здесь записаны UID, GID, домашняя папка и т.п.), `/etc/shadow` (здесь записан пароль) и `/etc/group` (отсюда нужно взять как минимум ту группу, GID которой прописан в passwd; как правило, она имеет имя, совпадающее с юзернеймом) из старой системы в новую.

Если в новой системе вы не будете создавать учёток при установке, то всё переносится простым дописыванием строк в этих файлах. Однако если дебиан заставит вас создать учётку, то копируемые юзернейм, UID, GID и названия групп могут оказаться заняты, и их нужно будет удалить (в принципе это тоже можно сделать простым удалением мешающихся строчек в ранее перечисленных файлах). Хотя если юзернейм, UID и GID свежесозданной учётки совпадут с таковыми из старой системы, то можно ничего не делать и ничего не переносить: всё и так заработает.

На заметку: если у вас единственная учётная запись, то скорее всего она будет иметь UID 1000 и GID 1000: многие линуксы начинают присваивание айдишников учёткам именно с этих значений.

Как вычитать юзернейм, UID и GID из файла passwd, можно узнать, например, [здесь](https://www.opennet.ru/docs/RUS/lame/x822.html).